# How can I edit pixels of DynamicImage using JuicyPixels (Haskell)?

Tags: image, haskell, types, pixel, signature

How can I do similar thing but with `DynamicImage` (the result of `example <- readImage "/filepath.png"`):

```
negative :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8
negative = pixelMap $ \(PixelRGBA8 r g b a) -> PixelRGBA8 (255 - r) (255 - g) (255 - b) a
```

And how it's working without any arguments despite signature?
I guess that's what I need, because there's no `writeJpg` function provided that does work with `Image` (not Dynamic) type.
I know about `dynamicPixelMap` function provided by JuicyPixels, but I do not actually understand how to work with it. It will be good if someone can explain it.

UPD:
I've found simple ***solution***:

```
negative :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8
```

```
dynamicImage <- readImage filepath
let image = convertRGBA8 <$> dynamicImage
let modified = negative <$> image
case modified of 
        Left err -> print err
        Right image -> saveJpgImage 100 outputFile $ ImageRGBA8 image
```

It's an example, my code is more complicated.

Comment: This question is... very unfocused. I count five different things you're actually requesting help with, none of which are strictly related to each other. It's difficult to respond usefully to a question like this in the SO format, especially when two of the questions you've raised are things that are frequently asked here and should be answered with links to other answers.

Comment: Edited, only main question left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by looking at why [`DynamicImage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture.html#t:DynamicImage) exists. Just looking at the definition is sufficient to make that clear: There are *lot* of different formats for color data in images. The input routines JuicyPixels provides preserve the color data the way it was stored in the file. But the `Image` type puts the color data format into the type. This is a problem in Haskell - if you make a function polymorphic, the *caller* gets to choose the concrete type, not the function itself. There's no way to say "this returns some `Image` type, depending on the input". So DynamicImage exists - it has a different constructor for each supported color data format. Matching on the constructor tells you the type of `Image` you're working with, so you can't get the data without also knowing what type it is.

Since the constructors are public, you can match on them to get an `Image` and use `pixelMap` on it... But I wouldn't. JPEG files are sometimes in CMYK space, not RGB. Logic in that space is *entirely* different - it's a subtractive space, rather than additive. And JuicyPixels provides tools to help you out here. The [`convertRGBA8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture.html#v:convertRGBA8) function takes a `DynamicImage` and does whatever colorspace conversion is necessary to give you an `Image PixelRBGA8`. The conversion will lose details in some cases, but it will get you the format in the example you provided.

Comment: I've found simple solution, that I'll mention in the post now